# Break out of a $(document).bind('keydown',function(e){}); function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
        key  = e.keyCode;
        if(key == 37){
            left();
        }else if(key == 38){
            up();
        }else if(key == 39){
            right();
        }else if(key == 40){
            down();
        }
    });
            alert("Hi");
});
```

"Hi" only alerts once how can i break out of a `$(document).bind` after its started? Something like `break;` or `return;` maybe?

Comment: Why are you expecting it to alert more than once? It will alert one time when the DOM is ready, that's it. It has nothing to do with the keydown event.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Both `break` and `return` are valid javascript commands.

Comment: What are you trying to do? "hi" alerts once because `$(document).ready()` fires once when the document dom is loaded and ready. Maybe you wanted to put the alert inside  the `keydown` event handler?

Comment: You can exit a function at any time with a return statement.  You can exit a loop with a break statement.

Answer (score 6):

"Hi" only alerts once because it is not within the `keydown` handler... it's within the `ready` handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind('keydown',function(e){
        key  = e.keyCode;
        if(key == 37){
            left();
        }else if(key == 38){
            up();
        }else if(key == 39){
            right();
        }else if(key == 40){
            down();
        }
    });// keydown handler ends here
            alert("Hi");
});
```

Also as a side note, try using the `console` methods instead of `alert()`, as it can be more descriptive and it's non-blocking.

**UPDATE**

I can see from the below comments you're quite confused as to what's actually happening in your code... So let's step through it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Here you're binding a handler to the `DOM ready` event. This gets fired when the browser has finished building the document structure. It doesn't take in to consideration any external assets that need to be loaded.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e){
```

Now we're binding a handler to the `keydown` event. Anything within the function (and *only* within the function) will be executed when the `keydown` event bubbles up to `document` level.

```
key = e.keyCode;
```

You assign the `keyCode` property of the event to a `key` variable. I suggest preceeding it with the keyword `var`, to maintain scope. `var key = e.keyCode;`

```
if(key == 37){
    left();
}else if(key == 38){
    up();
}else if(key == 39){
    right();
}else if(key == 40){
     down();
}
```

Now you're jumping through a series of `if`/`else` blocks, and calling `left`, `up`, `right` and `down` functions if the previously declared `key` variable matches one of your conditions.

```
});
```

This is the **END** of the `keydown` handler.

```
alert("Hi");
```

Here you `alert()` a message. This is done straight after the `keydown` handler is BOUND, but NOT after each or any execution of said handler. This line is executed ONCE, as part of the document `ready` handler.

```
});
```

This is the end of the document `ready` handler.

Comment: alright correction so im wondering how to get out of the keydown handler since it loops over and over checking for the keydowns but i want to break out of that and go to the alert again

Comment: @Caveman - You are clearly confused.  `keydown` doesn't _loop_, it executes every time a _key_ is pressed _down_.  Your current code will execute **ONE TIME** when the document is ready.  It _binds_ a keydown function to the document, but this event handler is never fired until the user presses a key.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: To continue on with what @jahroy is saying, the `keydown` handler will loop only when a key is pressed (and held). **ONLY** code within the handler is executed.

Comment: hmm alright i think i understand but is there anyway to unbind the keydown handler?

Comment: sure is. `.unbind()`. http://api.jquery.com/unbind -- But if you're using jQuery 1.7+, I suggest just using `.one()` http://api.jquery.com/one for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you dont want to use `keydown` for more than once.

You can either use [on](http://jqapi.com/#p=on) and [off()](http://jqapi.com/#p=off) like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keydown',function(e){
        key  = e.keyCode;
        if(key == 37){
            left();
        }else if(key == 38){
            up();
        }else if(key == 39){
            right();
        }else if(key == 40){
            down();
        }
        $(document).off('keydown'); 
    });// keydown handler ends here
            alert("Hi");
});
```

Or you can use [one()](http://jqapi.com/#p=one) which fires only once.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).one('keydown',function(e){
            key  = e.keyCode;
            if(key == 37){
                left();
            }else if(key == 38){
                up();
            }else if(key == 39){
                right();
            }else if(key == 40){
                down();
            }  
        });// keydown handler ends here
                alert("Hi");
    });
```

Comment: You should have waited for edit :) . May be he would want to run for more than 1 time or `off` on certain condition.